# Append variable name and date to PowerShell file output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put together a quick little script to help when I am using OpenSSL, for some reason I can't seem to get PowerShell to append the hostname to the front of my CSR file.  It is basically giving me things like `_09_26_2017.txt` instead of something like `hostname_09_26_2017.txt`.

I have the following

```
$date = Get-Date -format MM_dd_yyyy
$csrName = $siteName + "_" + $date

$siteName = Read-Host "Enter the site name"

.\openssl.exe req -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout "$siteName.pem" -out "$csrName.txt"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `$sitename` after you define `$csrname`. So

```
$csrName = $siteName + "_" + $date
```

is behaving as

```
$csrName = $null + "_" + $date
```

Simply define `$sitename` before you try to use by moving the line up:

```
$date = Get-Date -format MM_dd_yyyy
$siteName = Read-Host "Enter the site name"
$csrName = $siteName + "_" + $date

.\openssl.exe req -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -keyout "$siteName.pem" -out "$csrName.txt"
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that.  Yeah, that was it... Thank you so much for your help!